# Python:IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match)

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create `clinical` dataframe which contains a column `last_fu` that retains the `Last Alive Less Initial Pathologic Diagnosis Date Calculated Day Value` row in the `raw_clinical_patient` dataframe if the value is more than 2. The first four columns are header.

```
import pandas as pd

clinical = pd.DataFrame()
clinical["last_fu"] = raw_clinical_patient[raw_clinical_patient["Last Alive Less Initial Pathologic Diagnosis Date Calculated Day Value"].loc[4:].astype(int)>=2]
```

Traceback:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:5: UserWarning: Boolean Series key will be reindexed to match DataFrame index.
  """
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexingError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-55-e1f5dd93f92a> in <module>()
      3 # Read from the fifth row onwards
      4 clinical = pd.DataFrame()
----> 5 clinical["last_fu"] = raw_clinical_patient[raw_clinical_patient["Last Alive Less Initial Pathologic Diagnosis Date Calculated Day Value"].loc[4:].astype(int)>=2]

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in check_bool_indexer(index, key)
   2387         if mask.any():
   2388             raise IndexingError(
-> 2389                 "Unalignable boolean Series provided as "
   2390                 "indexer (index of the boolean Series and of "
   2391                 "the indexed object do not match)."

IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).


raw_clinical_patient[["#Other Patient ID", "Last Alive Less Initial Pathologic Diagnosis Date Calculated Day Value"]].head(10)
```

| #Other Patient ID | Last Alive Less Initial Pathologic Diagnosis Date Calculated Day Value |
| --- | --- |
| #Legacy DMP patient identifier (DMPnnnn) | Time interval from the last day on which a per... |
| #STRING | NUMBER |
| #1 | 1 |
| OTHER_PATIENT_ID | DAYS_TO_INITIAL_PATHOLOGIC_DIAGNOSIS |
| 30a1fe5e-5b12-472c-aa86-c2db8167ab23 | 0 |
| df3c1d61-79c1-43e9-971a-8029497ffeab | 0 |
| 3ac8f759-2df0-4ef5-913f-ce05b8dd8937 | 0 |
| 98714d95-b62e-4f34-9cd1-91542da463eb | 0 |
| fb75eb9d-05be-4e6b-a515-f39efb15e66c | 0 |
| c1f590eb-21ed-4939-adc5-0f7e6f485b56 | 0 |

Edit:

```
clinical["last_fu"] = (raw_clinical_patient
            .loc[4:]
            .copy()
            .astype(int)
            .query(f'{"Last Alive Less Initial Pathologic Diagnosis Date Calculated Day Value"}>=2'))
```

Also raises an error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-63-fc3f116ef0fb> in <module>()
      6             .loc[4:]
      7             .copy()
----> 8             .astype(int)
      9             .query(f'{"Last Alive Less Initial Pathologic Diagnosis Date Calculated Day Value"}>=2'))

8 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/_libs/lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.astype_intsafe()

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '30a1fe5e-5b12-472c-aa86-c2db8167ab23'
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem: Filtering with a boolean array with different size from the original dataframe. (As the error says)

Solution: Filter after subset.

```
long_name = 'Last Alive Less Initial Pathologic Diagnosis Date Calculated Day Value'
clinical = raw_clinical_patient.loc[4:].copy()
clinical = clinical.astype(int)
clinical = clinical[clinical[long_name]>=2]
```

or use chaining

```
clinical = (raw_clinical_patient
            .loc[4:]
            .copy()
            .astype(int)
            .query("'Last Alive Less Initial Pathologic Diagnosis Date Calculated Day Value'>=2"))
```

Becareful replacing strings:
For example

```
name = 'hello'
print(name) -> 'hello'
print(f'{name} world') -> 'hello world'
print(f'{hello} world') -> '{hello} world'
print('{name} world') -> '{name} world'
```

Comment: Your solution raised another error. Please view the question, under "edit". The error is raised because the code reads the `#Other Patient ID` column and not just the "long_name" column.

Comment: strings with letter f before quotes consider variables inside {} as their values.